# How can I constrain a generic parameter to implement basic math operators?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a way you can do this ?

I would like to have a collection class of T that would be able to do addition, substraction on the T type. I would like to keep T generic instead of having couple collections with the same code, but different types.

How would you constrain the generic T ?

Example: I would like to define a Collection(of T as IDoMaths). I wouldn't like to create my own integer etc classes with named methods to do the operations, because I think it would be slower. This part of the code is actually called very often and tends to be the bottleneck in perfomance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.

There's a workaround which Marc Gravell has [implemented](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) as part of [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) (with a [more general article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html) too). It's neat, but you do lose static type checking.

In a similar vein (in terms of losing type checking) the new `dynamic` feature of C# 4.0 lets you use operators in an arbitrary way, only resolving them at execution time:

```
dynamic x = 10.0;
dynamic y = 3.0;
double z = x / y; // z = 3.3333333 (double arithmetic)

dynamic a = 10;
dynamic b = 3;
int c = a / b; // c = 3 (integer arithmetic)
```

Just this afternoon I used this to implement a dynamic form of [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx). I'm about to benchmark it. Marc Gravell wrote a [blog post](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/05/exploring-40-expression-and-dynamic.html) about this recently, too.

If you're using VB, it's possible that just turning `Option Strict` off for the section of code where you want late binding will have the same effect, but I'm not as familiar with VB as I am with C#, I'm afraid.

Comment: This is a disappointing limitation in the current implementation of generics. Marc's implementation is the best I've seen as well at dealing with the problem. There are a few support articles on connect.microsoft.com related to this. You can find them here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=94264 and here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=325177 and here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=338861.

Comment: Did you intend the int example to use dynamic at all?

Comment: Thank you, my previous search kind of pointed these things out, but I wanted to know better.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an alternative solution that's more straightforward but involves a tiny bit more redundancy, you can try something I just whipped up. An advantage here is that it's fully typesafe.

Here's a quick a dirty version that implements + and - operations for int and float. It should be trivial to extend it to include more operations as well as support more primitive types (double, decimal, etc) -or even custom types for that matter. Just replace GenericMath with whatever you need.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gsInt = new GenericMath<int,IntOperators>();
        var gsFloat = new GenericMath<float,FloatOperators>();

        var intX = gsInt.Sum( 2, 3 );
        var floatX = gsFloat.Sum( 2.4f, 3.11f );
    }
}

interface IOperators<T>
{
    T Sum( T a, T b );
    T Difference( T a, T b );
}

sealed class IntOperators : IOperators<int>
{
    public int Sum( int a, int b ) { return a + b; }
    public int Difference( int a, int b ) { return a - b; }
}

sealed class FloatOperators : IOperators<float>
{
    public float Sum( float a, float b ) { return a + b; }
    public float Difference( float a, float b ) { return a + b; }
}

class GenericMath<T,Y>
    where Y : IOperators<T>, new()
{
    private readonly static Y Ops = new Y();

    public T Sum( T a, T b )
    {
        return Ops.Sum( a, b );
    }

    public T Difference( T a, T b )
    {
        return Ops.Difference( a, b );
    }
}
```

Comment: Full disclosure - you need to provide the IOperators implemeting type to any instances of classes that will perform generic math operations.